# Why does printf() output -1 for large integers?

Tags: c

I'm reading the second edition of K&R book and one of the exercises requires printing all maximum integer values defined in limits.h header. However, this...

```
printf("unsigned int: 0 to %d\n", UINT_MAX);
```

... outputs the following:

```
unsigned int: 0 to -1
```

How come I get -1? Anyone could explain this behaviour?

I'm using Digital Mars C compiler on Vista.

Comment: As an aside, your compiler should be able to warn you about this mistake.   If it didn't, see if you can turn on more warnings, or consider using a different compiler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because UINT_MAX resolves to -1 if treated as a signed integer. The reason for this is, that integers are represented in [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). As a consequence, -1 and 4294967296 (i.e. UINT_MAX) have the same bit representation (0xFFFFFFFF, i.e. all bits set) and that's why you get a -1 here.

**Update:**
If you use "%u" as the format string you will get the expected result.

Comment: "%u" works fine. I'm just wondering why the K&R guys didn't mention "%u" anywhere in their book... The question wouldn't even come up if they did.

Comment: i guess this is an error in the book, because the text in the printf statement suggests that the author wanted to show the properties of an unsigned int, which in fact he doesn't.

Comment: Of course K&R mention"%u" in their book (page 154 is one example). We're talking about K&R here.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning that the representation of integers and signed overflow are both implementation defined, and may not behave everywhere as described in this answer.

Answer (score 9):

In the printf, I believe %d is a signed decimal integer, try %u instead.

The max value of an unsigned int has the most significant bit set (it is all 1s). With a signed int, the most significant bit specifies negative numbers, so when you're printing an unsigned int as a signed int, printf thinks it is negative.